# how to remove last cookie set, with name delete_?

Tags: javascript, cookies

On my page you set links to other pages, like a startpage. You create a link to another page by write the address to it and choose a picture to represent it. What link and picture stores as cookies. You can also remove links by pressing a cross which creates another cookie named delete_ (the "_" represents which cookie it removes, delete1 removes link1 on the screen). But then someone regrets their removal and want the removed link back, which would be easy, just to remove the delete cookie. In "settings" i want a button to undo the last removal, remove the last cookie set, that starts with delete. 
 For example when i call console.log(document.cookies) with javascript i get back:

```
"link1=http://google.com; image1=http://...; delete1=true; link2=http://google.com; image2=http://...; link3=http://google.com; image3=http://...;  delete3=true; link4=http://google.com; image4=http://..."
```

If i pressed the undo button delete3=true cookie would be removed, and next time after delete1=true would be removed. How to accomplish this undo removal button?

Comment: I don't think there's any guarantee of cookie order.  If you must know the last one set, then you will probably need to add a timestamp.  If you explain the problem you're actually trying to solve with delete1, delete2, etc..., then we could probably suggest a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: If i give the delete cookies a timestamp instead of just "true", can you write some lines of code to delete the cookie that has the last timestamp?

Comment: Yes, code could be written to do that.  I think you'd probably be better off describing your actual problem and let people come up with an easier solution as the timestamp seems like more work than is probably necessary.  A common issue here on SO is that people ask for help with their chosen solution without describing the actual problem.  That means we don't have the ability to point you to a much better solution (which can often be done).

Comment: described the whole problem more now, hope you can help me!

Comment: So your problem actually has nothing to do with the cookies, but is about the undo functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to parse the cookies first with something like this:

```
function parseCookies() {
    str = document.cookie;
    var cookies = {};
    if (str === ""){return cookies;}
    var list = str.split(";");
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var cookie = list[i].trim();
        var p = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = cookie.substring(0,p);
        cookies[name] = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(p+1));
    }
    return cookies;
}
```

Then you can find the key of the highest delete with something like this:

```
function newestDelete(dict){
    console.log(dict);
    keylist = Object.keys(dict);
    delnums = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < keylist.length; i++){
        if(keylist[i].indexOf('delete') > -1){
            delnums.push(parseInt(keylist[i].replace('delete', '')));
        }
    }
    return "delete" + Math.max.apply(Math, delnums);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your work, but it isn't the cookie with highest delete i want removed. Its the latest set, because the cookies may not be set in order. sorry for bad explanation.